# (Re)Formatting HTML from multiple sources / text editors

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm working on a job board that accepts API posts from a number of other services.   We are constantly having trouble with the html that is received, eg `<div>` tags not being closed, inline  `CSS` styles being used etc.

Each service we  receive from has it's own rules and quirks. The problem is compounded because end users are copy/pasting from Word files into their wysiwyg editors, and only then do they get sent to us!

It seems that the only robust solution is to strip all of the html.  But that annoys users because all their bullets, bold text and headings are missing.

I've tried to use formulas that replace `<p>` tags with line breaks and suchlike but I've never managed to make it work satisfactorily.

Can anybody suggest an approach or solution that has worked for them?

*I'm specifically looking at ways to fix bad markup, as opposed to enforce good markup.  This is because on many occasions the end user is stuck with a bad system and most will not have the knowledge to understand or fix bad html.*

(We're on Classic ASP and in the process of migrating to MVC.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can partially solve this problem by implementing something like browser quirks mode. If client sends you good enough markup then post it as "rich" markup and respond with "success". And if client sends you something too messed up - post it as striped version and respond with the markup error list. if he wants cool "rich" markup he should fix it.

Comment: I like this idea because it puts the onus on the user to submit valid markup.  But in this particular instance I was hoping to fix bad markup rather than enforce good markup.  I'll update the question to reflect this

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox You can fix what can be fixed. That's why i said "good enough". And you can improve your method of parsing invalid markup gradually so more and more of it will be "good enough" And in the version with the "reduced markup" you still can use those tags which are parsable. But yes it's time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Display your clients responses inside iframe on your end.

Since Iframe will not interfere with your design layouts - client will see what they sent to you(and either fix their mistakes or get what they deserved) and your page will look intact and pretty.

Comment: Great tactic! And not too much work :)   I'm actually hoping to find a way to fix the submitted code (I updated the question to reflect this).  If I can't find a way to do that, I'll probably use this solution.

Comment: I have been in your shoes and as far as I know there is no way to predict and fix all possible markup issues. You can either strip all html or display given html the way it would not break yours.

Comment: @AllBlond  It should work. But it might look semi-ok only in the user's browser. And probably it can be exploited by the hackers.

Comment: With Iframes user will see what they sent and how they sent it in any browser not just their own, unless markup they used aren't supported. If they happy it will remain, if not they can fix it on their end. And if hackers would want to exploit any weaknesses bad mark up is the place to start.

Comment: @AllBlond Then clients will have to check it in all possible browsers themselves. About security vulnerability: In some cases you can give to the person markup that this person will post. If this markup wasn't properly sanitized you can steal HTTP cookie or another data from this person - if it can bypass Same-origin policy

Comment: @JAre and what it have to do with the question posted?

Comment: @AllBlond just pointing out that the proper implementation might require some extra work and some sort of a parser. This information might be useful but it do not directly relate to the question that's  why it's in the comments.